# I' m learning UITableView of iOS, why the last piece of cell in the UITableView can only show half of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I' m learning UITableView of iOS, why the last piece of cell in the UITableView, which means the UItableviewcell at the bottom of the tableView can only show half of it? The another half can be shown when I scroll it!

Comment: please show some code, be more clear and specific

Comment: Please look for a few online tutorials and implement a couple of table view based apps for practice. You will find most solutions on your own.

Comment: I' ll! This was the first time that I asked a question! I' ll keep all of these point in mind!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `UITableView` and any general `UIScrollView` is to give an ability to view large amount of data in the small phone screen. From your question explanation there is the following answer: your table content is not fit the screen so the last cell become partially hidden. When you scroll you can see it full-sized, but the first one become hidden. This is the general technique of scrollable content working

Comment: Thanks a lot, you' re right. I've figured it out by my self yesterday. Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: So would you mark that answer as correct?